# Como capturar outro elemento dentro de um loop para poder esconde-lo

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dificuldade, quero esconder uma certa lista quando se clica em um botão, problema tenho vários botões, eu consegui resolver atribuindo um id para o botão e fazendo várias verificações de if, contudo gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de algo mais prático.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.show-block');

for(let item of btn){
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let elemento = item.className;
        if(elemento.indexOf('ativo') !== -1){
            item.querySelector('ul');
            item.classList.add('show');
        }
        
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="description-item">
            <h2>Modo de preparo</h2>
            <a class="show-block">Esconder</a>
                <ul>
                    {% for preparation in recipe.preparation %}
                        <li>{{preparation}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="description-item">
            <h2>Modo de preparo</h2>
            <a class="show-block">Esconder</a>
                <ul>
                    {% for preparation in recipe.preparation %}
                        <li>{{preparation}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="description-item">
            <h2>Modo de preparo</h2>
            <a class="show-block">Esconder</a>
                <ul>
                    {% for preparation in recipe.preparation %}
                        <li>{{preparation}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="description-item">
            <h2>Modo de preparo</h2>
            <a class="show-block">Esconder</a>
                <ul>
                    {% for preparation in recipe.preparation %}
                        <li>{{preparation}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Quando eu tento capturar o UL e verifico dando um console.log(ul) o valor retornado é nullo, alguém teria alguma dica?

Comment: Seria melhor colocares o HTML renderizado em vêz do template que tens no servidor

Answer (score 0):

Alguns erros a ter em conta:

- `item.querySelector('ul')` vai dar vazio pois esses elementos são siblings (irmãos, no mesmo nível)
- `item.classList.add('show')` vai adicionar a classe ao `item`, que é o botão, presumo que querias adicional ao `ul`.

Testa assim:

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.show-block');

for (let item of btn) {
  const ul = item.closest('div').querySelector('ul');
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (elemento.indexOf('ativo') !== -1) {
      ul.classList.add('show');
    }

  })
}
```